# if it is not maintained, dies out

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It was generally accepted as indisputable and applicable to all natural phenomena that all heat in motion meets with the resistance of the environment. Thus, and [sic] electric current, overcoming the resistance of the wires, invariably heats them and, **if it is not maintained, dies out.** But in a conductor cooled nearly to the absolute zero this does not take place.

《大学英语典型误译分析》p226

Q：I want to know how to parse the blocked part, what dies out and what not maintained. Which one should I read it as :

1. electric current dies out if the resistance is not maintained
2. electric current dies out if the electric current is not maintained
3. the heat dies out if the electric current is not maintained

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a resource, it is an exercise from a textbook which says "it" refers to "electric current". I didn't get it that's why I asked here.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'an electric current' rather than 'and'? I think the meaning is (2) - the current is used up by heating the wire and dies out unless more electricity is supplied.

Comment: Right, it must be printed wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @wtdark
 when quoting a textbook here, please give the title and author(s) of the book, and  the page or section or chapter from which the quote is taken. This give proper credit. It also potentially allows others to find the source and obtain additional context. But even if context is not needed, or cannot be found, proper credit must still be given.

Comment: Thus, and=very fishy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "it" could be the electric current.

If the electric current isn't maintained -- that's to say, there aren't any devices along the wire to boost it -- then over a long enough stretch of resistant wire, the current will die out.

I say "could be" because to me "maintain" is not a natural word to apply to an electric current. But I'm not an electrician or electrical engineer, so I could be wrong about that.